# How to disable suspend with command line or config file?

Tags: server, hibernate

I want to disable suspend because my VPS goes into suspend and I cannot access it.

How I can do that?

Comment: Hibernate or suspend? Hibernation is disabled by default.

Comment: Oh really?

Maybe i should refer to suspend. Anyway i refered how to edit the config, if exists.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

On Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, I successfully used the following to disable suspend:

```
sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
```

And this to re-enable it:

```
sudo systemctl unmask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use gconf-editor

install that with

```
sudo apt-get install gconf-editor
```

and then look at

```
/apps/gnome-power-manager/timeout
```

Try setting `sleep_computer_ac` to `0`

maybe help

Comment: gnome? on a server?

Comment: Hello,

It needs a display or a GUI, my server don't have it.

There is some else way to edit that?

Answer (score -1):

This could have to do with that you are trying to run a bash script and that when you close your terminal it just quits this script, this is quite easy to solve.
Step 1 (install screen if not already installed)
sudo apt-get install screen 
Step 2 (using it!)
Now before you run your script just run screen!

If you want to get back to it later try running screen -R 
I hope this helped!